# Can't access views or change their values

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        getCurrentCountry()
    }

    private fun getCurrentCountry(){
        val api = Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build().create(CountryReq::class.java)
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val response = api.getCountries().awaitResponse()
            if(response.isSuccessful){
                val data = response.body()!!
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                    binding.selectCountry.text = "Demo text"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get data from an API and display it in a textview. But I can't seem to access the views or change its values from the GlobalScope.launch{} block.

Comment: Is there any error that Android Studio is giving you? If yes then please mention that here as well. P.S: CHECK THE LOGCAT!!

Comment: what is the view type of binding.selectCountry ?

Comment: Are you being able to access the views or change their values from outside the GlobalScope.launch{} block?

Comment: Have you logged response.isSuccessful value? Is it true or false ?

Comment: @NRUSINGHAMOHARANA it's a textview

Comment: @AbhishekChoudhary yes I can change it without any problems inside onCreate()

Comment: Btw use data?.let {//to what you want with data}. Cast without check (data!!) is NPE source.

Comment: can you try this@MainActivity.binding.selectCountry.text = "Demo text"